# JSON keys are shuffled in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm parsing the JSON from the web api, and Python seems to shuffle the keys when I iterate over them.

Original JSON on screenshot (it's right original ordering. No, it's not just alphabetically sorted):
[image: Original JSON]

My code:

```
data = requests.get('http://www.dota2.com/jsfeed/heropediadata?feeds=abilitydata&l=english').json()

for key in data['abilitydata']:
    print key
```

And output:

```
tiny_avalanche
rubick_fade_bolt
doom_bringer_devour
undying_flesh_golem
...
```

I've also tried to do this via urllib & json.loads() — it gives the same result.

How can I can achieve the original ordering?

Comment: Can you read it by object, and as you read each object add an order key.  I have never worked with JSON but I would imagine something like first reading the file and then iterating each object and as it is converted to JSON add a new attribute - the original order

Comment: A JSON object is, [by definition](http://www.json.org), "an unordered set of name/value pairs". You really shouldn't be using JSON objects (or perhaps you shouldn't even be using JSON) if the order in which the key-value pairs are originally specified is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an ordered dictionary and the object_pairs_hook argument of the loads method in the json package. Here is a working code example:

```
import json
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict

result = requests.get('http://www.dota2.com/jsfeed/heropediadata?feeds=abilitydata&l=english')
data = json.loads(result.text, object_pairs_hook = OrderedDict)
```

data will contain your dictionary keys in order

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me & this is the shortest solution :)

Answer (score 3):

As the others have said, `dict` is unordered. `collections.OrderedDict` is a dict subclass whose keys are ordered. The problem is that `json.load` returns a `dict` directly, and we can't just throw the result in an `OrderedDict`, as the order of the keys is already lost information by this point.

We need a way of telling `json.load` to return an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`.This can be done by implementing a custom `json.JSONDecoder` which supplies an `object_pairs_hook`. The `object_pairs_hook` is given a JSON object as a list of `(key, value)` tuples in the order that they appear in the JSON document. It should return the translation of this object to a Python object. We'll hand this list of tuples to the initializer for `collections.OrderedDict`, and that should do the trick.

Here's some code:

```
data = """
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "a_list": [1, 2, 3],
    "another_object": {
        "c": 3,
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
        },
    "last_key": 42
}
"""

decoder = json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
result = decoder.decode(data)
print(result)
```

which gives:

```
OrderedDict([('foo', 'bar'),
             ('a_list', [1, 2, 3]),
             ('another_object', OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('a', 1), ('b', 2)])),
             ('last_key', 42)])
```

Lastly, you might be wondering: "why is this so much extra work?". Well, JSON isn't meant to be treated as a data structure with any fixed order. You're going against the grain by doing this.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because Python dictionaries are unordered.

When you parse the JSON text, you get a dictionary. Because the dictionary type has no order, the keys can only be iterated over in an undefined order.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Is there a way to iterate over it with original ordering?

Comment: Even when using an order-maintaining Python type (ie. orderedict, which would have to be used through-and-through) is still incorrect to rely on this behavior in JSON; JSON itself explicitly establishes *no* ordering of key/value values.

Comment: @user2864740 that's just utility parser, not production-related code :)

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be in order?

Comment: Dictionaries, and their loose equivalents in other languages, are generally defined as unordered collections of key, value pairs. JSON has `Object` for that. The ordering of the keys in a JSON text is an illusion that exists because the text is serialised. If you parse it, then serialise it again, there's no assurance that the keys will be in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

`dict` type is a built-in type in Python. It is unordered.

If you want to be able to restore the order of keys in the dict, you can use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` class.

See this example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> data = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> data['pear'] = 1
>>> data['apple'] = 3
>>> data['orange'] = 2
>>> data['lemon'] = 4
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print data
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 3), ('orange', 2), ('lemon', 4)])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> data2 = dict()
>>> data2['pear'] = 1
>>> data2['apple'] = 3
>>> data2['orange'] = 2
>>> data2['lemon'] = 4
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print data2
{'orange': 2, 'lemon': 4, 'pear': 1, 'apple': 3}
>>>
```

For more info, go through this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict